# AI composing counterpoint?

Tags: composition, counterpoint, computer

I have heard of computer programs and AI that try to compose music based off the basic [counterpoint rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterpoint); are there currently any out in the web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Cope has released some code; how's your LISP?

http://artsites.ucsc.edu/faculty/cope/grad.html